# Entire Complex Function for dynamical systems

Tags: control-system, optimization

I am working on my master Thesis and I was going through the [1966 Thesis by K. P. Sriram](https://scholarship.rice.edu/bitstream/handle/1911/89289/RICE0327.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y).

Here, the author computes the switching curves for minimum time control of some "famous" systems using the concept of Entire Complex Function. I was wondering how to use the same techinique for systems of higher order which are decoupled by mean of state but have the same input. To be more specific, I have the following system :
$$
\begin{cases}
M\ddot{x}=u\\
\ddot{y}+2\gamma\dot{y}+\omega^2y=\dfrac{u}{b}
\end{cases}
$$
where \$M,b,\gamma,\omega>0\$.

How can I compute then the switching curve?

I tried to rewrite the system in state space, thus

\begin{equation}
 \dot{x}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & -\omega^2 & -2\gamma
\end{pmatrix}x+\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
\frac{1}{M}\\
0\\
\frac{1}{b}
\end{pmatrix}u 
\end{equation}

and then computing the transfer function. Since there are no measurements \$y\$, the transfer function would simply be :

\begin{equation}G(s)=(sI-A)^{-1}B\end{equation}

which is a four-by-one matrix. I thought then that to "cancel" all the poles, the matrix \$G(s)\$ should simply be losing rank. But it doesn't seem to work since there is a term which can never be zero. How do I proceed?

P.S. As stated by the author himself in the conclusion, this method CAN work for higher order systems.

P.P.S. If you don't want to read the full Thesis, and I can't blame you, just go from page 4 to 7/8.

Comment: First,I think this question would be better suited to MATH.SE. Second, why are you calculating the transfer function of the system? In the thesis you linked he finds the Laplace transform of a particular control signal, \$f(t)\$, applied to the system and then the Laplace transform of \$x(t)\$, the trajectory resulting from using such optimal control \$f(t)\$. The solution achieved also relies on eq. 3, so if your optimal control has more than one switching time it is not clear how you would determine the solution/your Eq. 3.

Comment: On math.SE I didn't get any useful answer. No, I know that $G(s)$ won't help, it was just an attempt. I'm in the same scenario as him about $f(t)$, the only difference is that I have two decoupled DE. Now, I get switching curve separately, all I have to do is to mix them together but I don't know how. For what concerns, the switches I know there are at most two.